# How to animate text overlays, in iMovie or similar

Tags: animation, imovie

I agreed to cut edit a video for the team I'm working with at university even though it's not really in my expertise (and I said that, I believe they overestimate me though).

I got sent a video that's supposed to serve as reference and I want to replicate a certain effect for blending in text. (best would be in iMovie but other programs are fine as long as there's a free demo like with Final Cut Pro)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAezj.jpg

Do you know whether there's a simple option for this in any program. I could of course try to do it frame by frame in affinity photo but I'd like something more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a program...

If you're referring to the title specifically, this can be accomplished is After Effects with relative ease.

You'll simply need to...

- create the three text box shapes
- the three lines of text
- parent-child them together
- animate them all with keyframes

If you're referring to the changing of speed effect, this can also be done in After Effects.  You can simply animate the speed with keyframes.